# Не получается центрировать ссылки по вертикали в flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Перепробовал кучу способов, куда я только не задавал align-items, ссылки просто прижимаются к верху и все. Прошу вашей помощи

```html
    <div class="header-nav">
        <div class="header-nav-content">
            <div class="header-nav-content-left">
                <a href="#">Currency : GBP</a>
            </div>
            <div class="header-nav-content-right">
                <a href="#">Register</a>
                <a href="#">Sign in</a>
                <a href="#">empty</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
    html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /*---------header-nav--------------*/

    .header-nav {
        background: #333;
        height: 45px;
    }

    .header-nav-content {
        display: flex;
        width: 57%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше не ограничивать высоту родительского блока, делая её фиксированной, а формировать за счет внутреннего контента

**Результат:**

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/*---------header-nav--------------*/

.header-nav {
  background: #333;
  /* height: 45px; */
}

.header-nav-content {
  display: flex;
  width: 57%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 13.5px 0;
}

.header-nav-content a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-nav">
  <div class="header-nav-content">
    <div class="header-nav-content-left">
      <a href="#">Currency : GBP</a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav-content-right">
      <a href="#">Register</a>
      <a href="#">Sign in</a>
      <a href="#">empty</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```